# Forming a basis for the eigenspace. How does this row-reduced matrix get transformed into this general solution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

This was an example problem during lecture. I understand the first part but not the second part

After finding eigenvalues $\lambda$=1 and $\lambda$=2 we now plug these numbers into our matrix
The RREF of the matrix where $\lambda$=1 is:
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

From this we can tell that x3 is a free variable and we get

$$s\left[
\begin{matrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
This is also our basis for the eigenspace at $\lambda$=1. This makes sense to me mostly. Though I'm not sure why the last value is one. There's nothing there. Do we assume that 0=1 in these scenarios?

When $\lambda$=2 things get even tricker. We get this RREF:
$$\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

Where x2 and x3 are free variables. From this the slides proceed to saying that

$$s\left[
\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
0 \\
1\\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

plus

$$t\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]$$

Where is the one at the bottom of the first vector coming from? And where is the 1 in the middle of the second vector coming from? I understand why -1 is on the top of the first. Moving that one to the other side changes it's sign. But I'm not sure what's happening with the rest of the numbers.

Comment: The first matrix is not in the echelon form.

Comment: @azif00 Yes it is, at least as I understand it. Either way it looks perfectly suitable for solving with free variables.

Comment: @TheoBendit. They were right. I accidentally included an extra 1. It was just recently edited out

Comment: What was the original matrix?

Comment: @ATR2400 The second matrix has one pivot, and two columns without pivots. This means there need to be **two** free variables. Your one non-zero equation $x_1 + x_3 = 0$ connects $x_1$ and $x_3$ to a single free variable (if $x_3 = s$, then $x_1 = -s$). The other free variable corresponds to $x_2$, which is unconstrained by any equation.

Comment: @TheoBendit Shouldn't x3=t instead of s as it's farther to the right? Which would make x1=-t

Comment: @ATR2400 Really doesn't matter. Call them $s$ and $t$, or $t$ and $s$, or $\xi$ and $\aleph$ if you prefer. They're just dummy variable names.

Comment: @TheoBendit So that sort of makes sense for the first row but what happens with the others? Where are the other 1s at the centre and middle of the vectors coming from when there's 0 rows with nothing to work with?

Comment: As I said before, we designate one free variable to $x_3$ and one to $x_2$ (i.e. the columns with no pivots). So, $x_3 = s$, $x_1 = -s$, and $x_2 = t$. This means the general solution is$$(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (-s, t, s) = s(-1, 0, 1) + t(0, 1, 0),$$i.e. a linear combination of the two vectors you listed. The $(0, 1, 0)$ comes from the fact that, not only was there no pivots in the second column, but there was no non-zero entry there at all. It meant that whatever system of equations you started with, none of the equations featured $x_2$. This leaves it unconstrained, with its own free variable!

Comment: @TheoBendit Ah that was very helpful! Thanks for sticking with me and helping me out. I know that this stuff is pretty basic but we've never actually dealt with things that look like this before in this class. There's always been some other number.